# How to create a shell script and run it?

Tags: raspberrypi

I'm currently doing my coursework for OCR A452 which is a research assessment which wants you to use forums to research the answers to your question. Anyway, my question is that I have created the text of the script but when I want to type it I open the terminal type "script (example) "script Humzah" and then type my code. Then I press control D and it exists but how do I open it back up and run it? That's what I don't understand? Thank you :)

Comment: `script` is shell session recording tool. It doesn't create shell scripts./

Answer (score 2):

To just see what was written, you can use `less`. We use the raw-control-chars option to convert back any colour codes and other junk that our PS1 contained when we recorded the session.

```
less -r typescript
```

`script` can actually record key-by-key playback though but you have to record timings. You need to alter your recording command slightly:

```
script -t 2> timingfile
```

This will output two files:

- `typescript` is what is written, and
- `timingfile` shows when each key was pressed.

With both files, you can replay the sequence:

```
scriptreplay -t timingfile typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `script` command is a tool to save the session. I think you want to do something different.

I use `vim hello.sh` to create following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello World!
```

and than you can run it by `bash hello.sh`, or you can set file permission to executable and run `./hello.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Use nano to make a .sh file, for example:

```
nano helloworld.sh
```

Type in something, like:

```
# Print HelloWorld to the terminal
echo HelloWorld
# Hashtag to comment out code
```

But at this point, you can't run it, to do that, type in:

```
chmod +x helloworld.sh
```

Now you should be able to run it with:

```
./helloworld.sh
```

You can also do this the hard way with C, type in

```
nano main.c
```

And type in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
system('echo HelloWorld')
```

You will need to install a C compiler, so:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

Compile it:
    gcc main.c -o Hi
Run it:

```
./Hi
```